# non-linear optimization in R using optim

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization

I'm a newbie in R!

I would like to find the best gamma distribution parameters to fit my experimental counts data. The `optim` function's help file says the first argument of the function should be the parameters to be optimized. So I tried :

```
x = as.matrix(seq(1,20,0.1))
yexp = dgamma(x,2,1)*100 + rnorm(length(x),0,1)
f = function(p,x,yexp) {sum((p[1]*dgamma(x,p[2],scale=p[3]) - yexp)^2)}
mod = optim(c(50,2,1),f(p,x,yexp))
```

I get the error message :

```
Error in f(p, x, yexp) : object 'p' not found
```

Any hint where I'm wrong?

Supplementary question : Is there any other way to fit counts data with standard distribution (gamma, inverse gaussian, etc?)

Comment: [fitdistr](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/fitdistr.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`optim` expects its second argument to be a function.  Also, the second and third arguments to `f` are fixed and need to be specified:

```
optim(c(50, 1, 2), f, x = x, yexp = yexp)
```

This would also work:

```
optim(c(50, 1, 2), function(p) f(p, x, yexp))
```

You could also use `nls` with default Nelder-Mead algorithm:

```
nls(yexp ~ a * dgamma(x, sh, scale=sc), start = list(a = 50, sh = 2, sc = 1))
```

or with plinear in which case no starting value is needed for the first parameter:

```
nls(c(yexp) ~ dgamma(x, sh, scale=sc), start = list(sh = 2, sc = 1), alg = "plinear")
```